# How worried should I be about the windows 8 drive repair?

Tags: windows-8

I just had windows 8 do a "Drive repair" on my HDD drive (D:). It did the "repair" successfully, and nothing **appears** to have been lost.

I am worried about what this means. Does this mean that the HDD is failing, or does it just mean that there was a minor glitch? And should I look into backing up and replacing my HDD right now?

I can easily take backups to an external drive right now, so I'm not too afraid if the drive actually fails.

Edit: It looks like I've got a ton of bad sectors now. Drive space has fallen from 750GB to 647GB.

Comment: Disk is failing... backup ASAP to ensure no data loss. You could use a Linux LiveCD to make a bit-by-bit duplicate of the failing disk to a new disk. You can then run `chkdsk /B` on the drive to get it to re-evaluate the copied "bad sectors" - i.e. clean the disk up.

Comment: @BigChris Thank you. I use windows, so I'm not sure what a linux thing has got to do with it. I am copying the entire drive onto a 2TB external drive - However, that is taking a long time and my computer has already crashed once.

Comment: Linux has a fantastic copying tool called `dd`. It is used to copy block level devices so you can copy files and entire devices if necessary so you, essentially, can "mirror" your failing hard disk to a new disk of the same or larger capacity. The "bad" blocks will also be copied but you can run `chkdsk /B` a couple of times and get it to re-check the bad clusters and if the clusters aren't actually bad it'll allow you to re-use them...

Comment: @BigChris But... I don't use linux?

Comment: Hence why I said "you could use a Linux LiveCD"... you can download and burn one at no cost and it doesn't make any changes to your computer. `dd` doesn't care about what OS is installed. I'm just saying that it could help you. It's up to you how you achieve your goal, many prefer such tools as Acronis, others like better control using such tools as dd...